# How do I calculate the sum of the individual digits of an integer and also print the original integer at the end?

Tags: python

I wish to create a Function in Python to calculate the sum of the individual digits of a given number
passed to it as a parameter.

My code is as follows:

```
number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
sum = 0

while(number > 0):
    remainder = number % 10
    sum = sum + remainder
    number = number //10

print("The sum of the digits of the number ",number," is: ", sum)
```

This code works up until the last print command where I need to print the original number + the statement + the sum. The problem is that the original number changes to 0 every time (the sum is correct).

How do I calculate this but also show the original number in the print command?

Comment: Why can't you just use another variable to store the number's original value, then print that at the end?

Comment: unrelated: Don't use `sum` as a variable identifier as there's a builtin function with the same name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep another variable to store the original number.

```
number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
original = number
# rest of the code here
```

---

Another approach to solve it:

You don't have to parse the number into `int`, treat it as a `str` as returned from `input()` function. Then iterate each character (digit) and add them.

```
number = input("Enter a number: ")
total = sum(int(d) for d in number)
print(total)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
number = input("Enter a number: ")
total = sum((int(x) for x in list(number)))
print("The sum of the digits of the number ", number," is: ", total)
```

As [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64126094/4810639) pointed out, the conversion to `int` isn't even required since we only operate a character at a time.

Comment: Was about to post something similar... `digit_sum = sum([int(x) for x in '123'])`

Comment: Converting the number to a string is not a clean way to represent the actual sum of the digits, as you're creating an unnecessary object. A better solution is creating a separate function that returns the sum of the digits without creating a string.

Comment: @AndrewMascillaro that's true but for one-liners this is hard to beat ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: We don't know why OP needed to sum up the digits via modulus operations, so I think a better answer would be to just give them what they're asking for while still preserving their code, rather than rewriting it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it completely without a conversion to int:

```
ORD0 = ord('0')
number = input("Enter a number: ")
nsum = sum(ord(ch) - ORD0 for ch in number)
```

It will compute garbage, it someone enters not a number